# basic questions C*-morphisms on $B(\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am following a course in functional analysis. In a question we are given the properties of a $C^*$-algebra, and I have proved that $B(\mathcal{H})$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is Hilbert space, is a $C^*$-algebra. I now need to prove that an isomorphism $f:\mathcal{H}_1 \to \mathcal{H}_2$, where $\mathcal{H}_1,\mathcal{H}_2$ Hilbert spaces, gives rise to a $C^*$- morphism $F:B(\mathcal{H}_1)\to B(\mathcal{H}_2)$. I tried to define $F(T) := f\circ T\circ f^{-1}$. This is well defined and bounded because of the boundedness of $T$. The $C^*$-multiplication of $F$ is easy to proof but I am stuck trying to show that $F(T^*) = F(T)^*$. my attempt: for $x,y \in \mathcal{H}_2$:
\begin{align*}<x,F(T)^*y>&= <F(T)x,y>=<f\circ T\circ f^{-1}x,y>=<T\circ f^{-1}x,f^*y>\\
&=<f^{-1}x,T^*\circ f^*y>= <x,f^{-1*}\circ T^*\circ f^*y>= <x,F(T)^*y>.
\end{align*}
So somehow I should be allowed to do something with $f^{-1}$ and $f^*$ but I am not sure how and what is allowed. I hope someone can give me a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f$ is an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces. This means that $f$ preserves the inner product, i.e.
$$ \langle f(v_1), f(v_2) \rangle = \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle \ \ \ \ \ {\rm for \ \ } v_1, v_2, \in\mathcal H_1.$$

If we apply this to $v_1 = T \circ f^{-1}(x)$ and $v_2 = f^{-1}(y)$, we have
$$ \langle f \circ T \circ f^{-1}(x), y \rangle = \langle T \circ f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y) \rangle.$$

Later on, you can apply the same logic to show that
$$ \langle f^{-1}(x), T^\star \circ f^{-1}(y) \rangle = \langle x, f \circ T^\star \circ f^{-1}(y) \rangle, $$
and this is precisely the fix that you want.

Comment: Wow this makes it very clear! thank you. However, in my textbook (Rynne & Youngson) they do define the adjoint of a bounded map between two different complex Hilbert spaces (definition 6.2).

Comment: @Lou95 Yeah, I suppose it is reasonable to do so, and it is not hard for me to guess what the definition is. In that case, what we have shown is that $f^\star = f^{-1}$... which looks rather similar to the definition of a unitary matrix, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Of course, really pretty! This helps a lot with my insight in how these operators work. Thanks again :)